# Big-O notation, summation and integration

Tags: calculus

> \begin{align*}\sum_{1 \leqslant d \leqslant x} \frac{1}{d} &= \sum_{1 \leqslant d \leqslant x} \left( \int_{d}^{d + 1} \frac{dt}{t} + O\left(\frac{1}{d^2}\right) \right) \\
> &= \log x + O(1)
> \end{align*}

I'm trying to show that this is true. I see where the last line comes from, but I'm confused by where the integral comes from. Can anyone offer any intuition/explanation?

Comment: take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the graph of $y = 1/t$. Beneath it, sketch a box from $t = 1$ to $t = 2$, and with height $1/2$; draw another for $2 < t < 3$, with height $1/3$, adn so on. The sum of the box areas is the sum on the left; each box area is less than the area of the corresponding integral. So it's just an estimate of the lower sum of an integral.

(What's not clear in your formula is whether $x$ is meant to be an integer, and if not, what the sum on the left actually means...but that's a separate problem.)